# Aligning list items in css

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble aligning items in CSS, i wish to have two unordered list side by side, each alpha item should be aligned with it's corresponding roman item, no matter the size of either the alpha or roman item. Here is the code I have: http://jsfiddle.net/u7sq8rL7/17/

```css
.o {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}

.m {
  list-style-type: lower-roman;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <ul class="o">
    <li>hello you have are you doing today, happy to meet you</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>alpha</li>
    <li>small</li>
    <li>friend</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="m">
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>enemy</li>
    <li>tall</li>
    <li>beta</li>
    <li>I'm fine thank you hope you are fine too.</li>
  </ul>
</ol>
```

[image: Result intended]

Comment: can you show image how you would like to align this HTML?

Comment: This sounds rather like a table could be the correct choice to begin with, if there is a direct relation between the items on both lists ...

Comment: @CBroe very interesting but I am interested in how to number the elements in the table.

Comment: Check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

http://jsfiddle.net/LLyLutc2/

```
<ol>
  <ul class="o">
    <li>hello you have are you doing today, happy to meet you</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>alpha</li>
    <li>small</li>
    <li>friend</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="m">
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>enemy</li>
    <li>tall</li>
    <li>beta</li>
    <li>I'm fine thank you hope you are fine too.</li>
  </ul>
</ol>
<p>Some other content is here....</p>

.o {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}

.m {
  list-style-type: lower-roman;
}

ul, p  {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: When a list-item is too long, i wish to use `white-space: pre-wrap`, but your solution seems not to work with

Answer (score 0):

Here is an edited working fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/ash06229/u7sq8rL7/26/

```
ol {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  padding: 0 20px 0;
}
.o {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.m {
  list-style-type: lower-roman;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Ok just saw your solution but if then i use `white-space: pre-wrap;` on the list-items, they do not align accordingly anymore, that is the biggest issue I wish to solve

Comment: Can you share your exact problem with a screenshot of output?

Comment: Just added an image in the question to show what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, what I guess is below is something you need?

```
.o {
      list-style-type: lower-alpha;
      float: left;
      width: 40%
    }

    .m {
      list-style-type: lower-roman;
      float: left;
      width: 50%
    }
```

Comment: does this work for you? In above code you can add ol {overflow:hidden}

Answer (score 0):

```css
.o {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
     float: left;
    width: 25%;
 }

.m {
  list-style-type: lower-roman;
  float: right;
 }
```

```html
<ol>
 <ul class="o">
  <li>hello you have are you doing today, happy to meet you</li>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>alpha</li>
  <li>small</li>
  <li>friend</li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="m">
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>enemy</li>
  <li>tall</li>
  <li>beta</li>
  <li>I'm fine thank you hope you are fine too.</li>
 </ul>
</ol>
```

Comment: item "a" is matching with item 'i', 'ii' and 'iii', which is not what I expect

Comment: what do you mean that's why I am asking for image what you want exactly.

Comment: Just added an image to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display: inline-block` both o and m classes:

```
<style>
 .o {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: lower-alpha;
  }

.m {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: lower-roman;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ol {
  display: flex;
}

.o {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}

.m {
  list-style-type: lower-roman;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <ul class="o">
    <li>hello you have are you doing today, happy to meet you</li>
    <li>hello you have are you doing today, happy to meet you</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="m">
    <li>hello you have are you doing today, happy to meet you</li>
    <li>hello you have are you doing today, happy to meet you</li>
  </ul>
</ol>
<p>Some other content is here....</p>
```

Comment: The item a seems to be linked to both item i and ii. Could you make it to be a one on one match?

Comment: if you look at "to meet you", it's like it corresponds to "enemy". If the items get big and bigger, the numbering on both side would be odd.

Comment: You have to change your html

Comment: ok so what should I have them? The most important for me is the numbering and the alignment.